# laravel database session driver and websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

so i'm using the database session driver in laravel and i've faced this weird problem while using socket io. if i connect to the route /room/id **without enabling socket.io** then it counts as a one connection and is inserted in the database correctly [image: correctly inserted]

**however if i enable socket.io** things get weird and instead of inserting a single row, multiple rows with different id get inserted for each connection and the user_agent column becomes empty just like so
[image: incorrectly inserted]